# update receiving data from server in java

Tags: java, networking, tcp

I have wright a program that receives some data from server and shows them in client (Graphic not console) this works, but when my program gets new data I should run the client side again to load  new data.

The question is how can I show the data when the client is running?

I just wanna clarify my question

this is what I've done in server side

```
private void transferData() {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String data;
    for (Bubble bubble : field.getBubbles()) {
        data = bubble.getX() + " " + bubble.getY() + " " + bubble.getRadius() + " " + bubble.getColor().getRed() + " " + bubble.getColor().getGreen() + " " + bubble.getColor().getBlue() + " ";
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(prefix + e);
        }
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (isAlive) {
        transferData();
    }
}
```

and the client side

```
public void run() {
    if (connection == null || !connection.isConnected()) {
        System.out.println(prefix + "connecting to server failed!");
        return;
    }
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        byte[] inputInformation = new byte[2048];
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        inputStream.read(inputInformation);
        String s = new String(inputInformation);
        System.out.println(s);
        String[] y = s.split("\\s");
        intData = new int[6];
        for (int j = 0; j < y.length / 6; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                intData[i] = Integer.parseInt(y[6 * j + i]);
            }
            //add something to gui
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (isAlive) {
            //do sth
        repaint();
        try {
            //it's obvious, refresh rate !
            Thread.sleep(1000 / REFRESH_RATE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(prefix + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really clear, but basically you should have one thread that is continuously receiving data (i.e. reading the socket connected with the server), synchronized with the GUI thread: when the first thread receives a message, it communicates with the GUI thread in order to update it, and then come back to read the socket again.

Example:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GUIThread gui = new GUIThread(); //create gui thread
        //create connection thread (with reference to gui GUI thread)
        ConnectionThread c = new ConnectionThread(gui);
        //start to run both threads
        gui.start();
        c.start();

    }
}

class GUIThread extends Thread {

    private final JFrame f;
    private final JTextArea t;

    public GUIThread() {
        f = new JFrame(); //gui main window
        t = new JTextArea("Waiting data...\n", 32, 64); //to display the data
        f.add(t);
        f.pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { //method running on a separated thread
        f.setVisible(true); //show the gui
    }

    synchronized public void showData(String data) { //method called by the ConnectionThread
        t.append(data + '\n'); //to update the gui to show the data
    }


}

class ConnectionThread extends Thread {

    private final GUIThread gui;

    public ConnectionThread(GUIThread gui) {
        this.gui = gui; //store reference to the gui thread
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("www.google.com", 80); //open a client connection
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())); //to read
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()); //to write (only if you need)
            String request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n"; //a string to send to the server
            writer.write(request, 0, request.length()); //in order to receive some data back (to simulate your situation)
            writer.flush();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //read data from the connection until the connection is closed
                gui.showData(line); //update the gui
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //eventually exception handling
            System.err.println(ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: OK this is exactly the problem can you provide an example of what you say how to read the socket again and again ?

Comment: @siavash pleas look at the added example